# How to properly position a page scope block with BEM

Tags: html, css, bem

Below is my current header structure. The `page` (root) component is implied.

As you see `social-links` block's geometry is currently handled by the `header__social-links` mix (absolute position relative to the header).

How do I properly extract `social-links` to the global (page) scope making it an independent block (fixed position on the page)?

If I introduce the `site` or `page` block wrapping the `header` then I can apply `page__social-links` mix to solve that. Should `header` then be transformed into the `page__header`?

```
<body>

    <header class="header hero" role="banner">

      <img class="header__logo" src="assets/logo.png" alt="">

      <div class="social-links header__social-links">
        <a class="link social-links__link" href="#">
          <svg class="social-links__icon">...</svg>
        </a>
        ...
        <a class="link social-links__link social-links__link--last" href="#">
          <svg class="social-links__icon">...</svg>          
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar header__navbar">
        <nav class="site-links navbar__site-links">
          <a class="link site-links__link" href="#">1</a>
          <a class="link site-links__link" href="#">2</a>
          <a class="link site-links__link" href="#">3</a>
          <a class="link site-links__link" href="#">4</a>
        </nav>
      </div>

    </header>
    ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate the two scopes `header` and `social-links` as parent / child. It is important that BEM blocks are isolated. When using two classes from different blocks on the same elements, we risks future interference, and regression, when we will update one block without checking the other one.

The separation is also important to be able to move the `social-links` block.

```js
// Show the fixed header on scroll
var fixedHeader = document.querySelector('.page__social-links');

document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (window.scrollY > 100) {
    fixedHeader.classList.remove('page__social-links--hidden');
  } else {
    fixedHeader.classList.add('page__social-links--hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 300vh;
}

.page__social-links {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: hotpink;
}

/* Hide the fixed header by default */
.page__social-links--hidden {
  display: none;
}

.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid hotpink;
}

.social-links {
  text-align: center;
}

.social-links__link {
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  line-height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="page__header">
    <header class="header hero" role="banner">
      <img class="header__logo" src="assets/logo.png" alt="" />

      <div class="header__social-links">
        <div class="social-links">
          <a class="link social-links__link" href="#">
            twitter
          </a>
          <a class="link social-links__link social-links__link--last" href="#">
            facebook          
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <div class="page__social-links page__social-links--hidden">
    <div class="social-links">
      <a class="link social-links__link" href="#">
        twitter
      </a>
      <a class="link social-links__link social-links__link--last" href="#">
        facebook          
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Cheers,
Thomas.

Comment: link - is a reusable atomic component, which is totally legit to be used under BEM methodology. As for prefixes, I also haven't seen a requirement for that. Nevertheless I've seen combinations of BEM + SMACSS which use prefixes. I wish I could solve the elementary question not the prefix problem. I didn't put any non-bem classes for reviewers. I apreciate your point 1 (on probable interference). Yet, your post really doesn't answer my question: 'How do I properly extract social-links to the global (page) scope making it an independent block (fixed position on the page)?'

Comment: If I didn't answer the question... I should not understand the question.
I will think about it and update my answer. If all your classes are BEM ones, prefix is not needed. But `link site-links__link` doesn't seems great. You use an element of `site-links` as a modifier of `link` you broke isolation.

Comment: ok, thank you. Regarding `link + site-links__link` stuff, well, why did I break the isolation? `link` provides basic stuff, like {cursor: pointer;color:#fff;} and so on. Then `site-links__link` extends it.

Comment: Yes, so `site-links__link` is not autonomous, it will always need `link`. You can use atomic classes with BEM, for generic modifier, for example `u-uppercase`

Comment: I made an update with a demonstration of what it could be.

Comment: Yes, this is it!